# Tracking GPS location of my device

Tags: android, gps

When I run it the output is showing that "permission denied", thats in my else part.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest; 
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient client;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private Location lastLocation;
private Marker currentLocationMarker;
public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE=99;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready 
 to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ){
                //permission is granted
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    if (client == null){
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            }
            else //permission denied
            {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            return;
    }
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the 
 camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be 
 prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once 
  the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
if 
(ContextCompat.
checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATI
 ON) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
 }


 protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
          .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    client.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);

locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY 
);

    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 

Manifest
 .permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
{

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, 
locationRequest, this);
    }
}



public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, 
Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if 

(Activity
Compat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.A
CCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]
{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},REQUEST_LOCATION_CODE);

        }
        return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    lastLocation = location;

    if(currentLocationMarker != null) {
        currentLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new 
LatLng(location.getLongitude(),location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("current location");



markerOptions.icon
(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory
.HUE_BLUE));
    currentLocationMarker=mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(10));

    if (client != null){
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(client 
,this);
    }

}
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

and my android manifest file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.kerthi.map2">


<permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

  </manifest>
```

I think there is a mistake in the `if`, I am not sure. Please kindly help me.
Is there anything else which I should add?

Comment: Have you added Google API key? is the key correct?

Comment: @AjilO.You do not need any API key for GPS

Comment: yup i am getting the map

Answer (score 0):

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.oit.test.mygoogle">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <permission
            android:name="com.sa.com.oit.test.mygoogle.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/shiv"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

            <activity
                android:name=".MapsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            </activity>

            <activity
                android:name=".MapLocationActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

MainActivity

```
package com.oit.test.mygoogle;

import android.*;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.LocationSource;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity


        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener

{

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    public static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 100;
    double mLatitude;
    double mLongitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        else
        {
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            }
        }

        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {
                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);

                        mapFrag.getMapAsync(MapLocationActivity.this);
                    }
                });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();

        //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mGoogleMap=googleMap;
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
                } else {
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));
                    LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(mLatitude, mLongitude);
                    CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 10);
                    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
    {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
  /*      mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);*/
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        mLastLocation = location;
     /*   if (mCurrLocationMarker != null)
        {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }*/
        LatLng opt = new LatLng(22.57, 88.43);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(opt).title("Shivi").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.marker)));

        LatLng opt2 = new LatLng(22.50, 88.53);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(opt2).title("Sarthak").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.marker)));

        LatLng opt3 = new LatLng(22.67, 88.35);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(opt3).title("Mitra").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.marker)));

        LatLng opt4 = new LatLng(22.47, 88.43);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(opt4).title("Boss").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.marker)));
        mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(latLng)      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                .zoom(10)                   // Sets the zoom
                .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
      /*  //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));*/

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
        {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

    public boolean checkLocationPermission()
    {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
            {
                // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            else
            {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
    {
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION:
            {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    {

                        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                        {
                            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
                        }

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null)
                        {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please briefly explain what have you changed in posted manifest file to resolve "permission denied" issue

Comment: add this dependencies first

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}

dependencies { compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'

}

Comment: just try it once